# how to get public key with Crypt_RSA

Tags: php, public-key, crypt, phpseclib

I have coded a simple test, but it sent me: "Unverified", I guess because I am using the whole certificate instead of the public key. What method gives me public key?

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setPassword('here I include password');
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('i.pem')); // private key
$plaintext = 'abc';
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$signature = $rsa->sign($plaintext);
//now the verification
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('instancia_ope.crt')); //here maybe WRONG
echo $rsa->verify($plaintext, $signature) ? 'Verified' : 'Unverified';
```

Comment: the line //here maybe WRONG, indicates the public key file

Comment: PLease mention packages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991887/how-to-get-public-key-with-crypt

Comment: SteAP, you mean in the subject line? or where, and what package?

Comment: @SteAp is a pear package.  If you don't know what it is google it and you probably shouldn't be answering.

Comment: I'm aware of this fact. Nevertheless, I propose to always include references - since this would assist people who'd like to answer. No longer maintained PEAR package http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_RSA migrated to phpseclib http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

Ah sorry your verifying, try this

```
$rsa->loadKey($rsa->getPublicKey()); 
echo $rsa->verify($plaintext, $signature) ? 'Verified' : 'Unverified';
```

Comment: In my code what would be the $encrypted_text you mentioned? the $signature variable? thanks for clarify